# Strange behavior while listing directories in Jenkinsfile where docker is running as agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, cicd

I am running a very basic Jenkinsfile, docker as agent. Below is the Jenkinsfile.

```
pipeline{
    agent none
    stages{
        stage('Tomcat version'){
            agent{
                docker {image 'tomcat:jre21-temurin'}
            }
            steps{
                // below ls command showing directories inside the container 
                sh 'ls /usr/local'

                //but below ls and pwd command showing directories present in cuurrent jenkins workspace 
                sh 'ls'
                sh 'pwd'

                //this command runs inside container
                sh 'cat /usr/local/tomcat/RELEASE-NOTES | grep "Apache Tomcat Version"'

                // This command also runs inside container
                sh 'ls /usr/local'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In above Jenkinsfile I am seeing very strange behavior as I have explained in every step.

Can someone please helm me to understand, what exactly happening here?

Comment: Any luck? i am having same issue.

Comment: Please include the console output for review as well.